# How to fix error netfx.force.conflicts required while installing app after publish

Tags: c#, visual-studio, publish

I've tried to publish my app. Publish went okay but as I try to install the app there is an error `"Unable to install or run the application. The application requires that assembly netfx.force.conflicts Version 0.0.0.0 be installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) first"`

Any idea what to do? I've tried deleting my bin folder before publish but it went the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to right-click on a project, go to **properties**, then to **Publish** and to **Application Files**. Then I had to change all dlls publish status to **include** (instead of **prerequisite**).